# Windows Phone SDK Paradox: "Xde couldn't find an IPv4 address.." and "The emulator couldn't determine the host's IP address..."

Tags: visual-studio, ip, windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

A few useful pieces of information: I'm running Windows 8 Professional on a custom-built rig, and I am using a 'WiFi dongle' to connect my computer to the local router. I am using a home network, not a public/work/school network.

I installed the Windows Phone SDK. Piece of strawberry cheesecake so far. Coded my first simple browser app (as detailed on the Windows Phone Dev site) and hit the Run button, expecting my app to come to life and breathe in links and breathe out websites!

But instead, I got this:

```
Something happened while creating a switch: 
Xde couldn't find an IPv4 address for the host machine.
```

In this case, the emulator **wouldn't run at all.** And so, I did my research and found out that the solution was this:

- Remove **all** the switches from Hyper-V Manager's "Virtual Switch Manager", and make a new Internal one called *Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch*.

I did, and the error did NOT show up again but it did screw up my WiFi and Bluetooth adapters (which I had to do a system restore to solve) and now both WiFi and Bluetooth peripherals are working again.

However, I got this error instead when running the emulator again:

```
The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to connect to the Windows 
Phone operating system:

The emulator couldn't determine the host IP address, which is used to 
communicate with the guest virtual machine.

Some functionality may be disabled.
```

In this case, **the emulator did run, but I couldn't find my app anywhere.** I did some research again and found that the solution to this was:

- Delete the *Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch* from Hyper-V Manager's Virtual Switch Manager.

Now, I created the switch to solve the problem in the first place. But I did delete it, for the heck of trying everything out. And no surprise there but, it went back to the first error.

I am now stuck in this paradox and have no idea how to escape it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which type of connection you have? Dynamic or static? You were using laptop or desktop?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq Define "type of connection", please, as I'm an absolute newbie! And I was using my own custom built rig (desktop).

Answer (score 5):

follow the following steps to solve this problem

1.go to network and sharing center

2.go to change adapter setting

3.go to v Ethernet (internal Ethernet port windows phone emulator internal switch)

4.right click it and enable it(if already enabled then disable and enable it again).

**Remove any Cisco VPN's or similar connections. I have found this VPN client works as a replacement to Cisco   https://www.shrew.net/**

For me shrew soft version 2.1.7 was the only version that worked.

Comment: Did all that I could until I uninstalled the Cisco VPN and all started to work. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I did all that, but there is a VPN on my computer (it's installed by the IT department, and I don't know how to disable it), and I still cannot connect to the emulator... Any ideas?

Comment: reinstall windows so you are the admin ;)